# EUCompliance data in POST_PRODUCT_DATA call does not get accepted

Tags: xml, xsd, amazon-mws

We're trying to build an application for uploading products to Amazon in bulk using the python-amazon-mws repository. We can post regular products using XML just fine, but some of our inventory requires the addition of GHS hazard statements and we cannot find out where/how to add them. The documentation is lacking and the error messages returned by the API are also not helpful. This is the official XSD: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/EUCompliance.xsd

The EUCompliance element is also referenced in the Product.xsd, but wherever we place it, it does not get accepted. This is a mock-up of the XML we used:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>

    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <Product>
            [...]
            <DescriptionData>
                [...]

                <GHSClassificationClass>corrosive</GHSClassificationClass>

                <EUCompliance>
                    <EuLabelingHazard>H371</EuLabelingHazard>
                </EUCompliance>

            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>                    
                [...]
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    [...]        
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

The error messages are always similar, along the lines of

> Invalid content was found starting with element ‘EUCompliance’. One of […] was expected.

We have tried to follow the suggestions of these messages, placing the data under other parent elements (e.g. DescriptionData, GHSClassificationClass, OtherItemAttributes...), but no success. We also looked into getting the full XML of existing products, but there doesn't seem to be such a functionality and we have probably worked through every bit of documentation there is.

Does anyone know where and how to place this data to successfully add it to any products, are we missing something obvious? We are thankful for any input.

Answer (score 1):

We've found a way to get the EUCompliace data into new products, but it is somewhat tedious. We cannot verify whether this is the *right* way, since the Amazon MWS support is not very supportive, but it is *one* way:

The key is to **not** include any EUCompliance data under 'ProductData' when first uploading a new product using the *POST_PRODUCT_DATA* call. You simply hand over your basic category/product type information, e.g:

```
[...]
<ProductData>
    <AutoAccessory>
        <ProductType>
            <Motorcyclepart>
            </Motorcyclepart>
        </ProductType>
    </AutoAccessory>
</ProductData>
[...]
```

This data should be accepted by MWS. After your basic product is uploaded, you then need to do a second *POST_PRODUCT_DATA* call, updating your just created product. In this call you then replace everything within the 'ProductData' with your desired EUCompliance data:

```
[...]
<ProductData>
    <EUCompliance>                      
        <EuLabelingHazard>H224</EuLabelingHazard>
        <EuLabelingHazard>H300</EuLabelingHazard>
        <EuLabelingHazard>H311</EuLabelingHazard>
    </EUCompliance>
</ProductData>
[...]
```

For whatever reason, handing over the EUCompliance data seperately works just fine. This will update your product and display the much needed GHS hazard statements, pictograms, etc.